# Отменить оплату со внутреннего счета

Tags: php, битрикс

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:sale.order.ajax", "uni_sale_order_ajax", Array(
    "PATH_TO_BASKET" => "/personal/cart/",  // Страница корзины
    "PATH_TO_PERSONAL" => "/personal/order/",   // Страница персонального раздела
    "PATH_TO_PAYMENT" => "/personal/order/payment/",    // Страница подключения платежной системы
    "PATH_TO_AUTH" => "/personal/profile/", // Страница авторизации
    "PAY_FROM_ACCOUNT" => "N",  // Позволять оплачивать с внутреннего счета
    "COUNT_DELIVERY_TAX" => "N",    // Рассчитывать налог для доставки
    "COUNT_DISCOUNT_4_ALL_QUANTITY" => "N", // Рассчитывать скидку для каждой позиции (на все количество товара)
    "ONLY_FULL_PAY_FROM_ACCOUNT" => "N",    // Позволять оплачивать с внутреннего счета только в полном объеме
    "ALLOW_AUTO_REGISTER" => "N",   // Оформлять заказ с автоматической регистрацией пользователя
    "SEND_NEW_USER_NOTIFY" => "N",  // Отправлять пользователю письмо, что он зарегистрирован на сайте
    "DELIVERY_NO_AJAX" => "Y",  // Рассчитывать стоимость доставки сразу
    "DELIVERY_NO_SESSION" => "N",   // Проверять сессию при оформлении заказа
    "TEMPLATE_LOCATION" => ".default",  // Шаблон местоположения
    "DELIVERY_TO_PAYSYSTEM" => "d2p",   // Последовательность оформления
    "SET_TITLE" => "Y", // Устанавливать заголовок страницы
    "USE_PREPAYMENT" => "N",    // Использовать предавторизацию для оформления заказа (PayPal Express Checkout)
    "PROP_1" => "", // Не показывать свойства для типа плательщика "Физическое лицо" (s1)
    "PROP_2" => "", // Не показывать свойства для типа плательщика "Юридическое лицо" (s1)
    ),
    false
);

?>
```

вроде правильно, но оплачивается со внутреннего счета.
Я даже в шаблоне `template.php` закомментировала строку `//include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$templateFolder."/paysystem.php");`

UPD

```html
$arParams["PAY_FROM_ACCOUNT"] ="N" ;
$arParams["COUNT_DELIVERY_TAX"] ="N"; 
$arParams["COUNT_DISCOUNT_4_ALL_QUANTITY"] = "N";
$arParams["ONLY_FULL_PAY_FROM_ACCOUNT"] ="N";
$arParams["DELIVERY_NO_AJAX"] = (($arParams["DELIVERY_NO_AJAX"] == "Y") ? "Y" : "N");
$arParams["USE_PREPAYMENT"] = $arParams["USE_PREPAYMENT"] == 'Y' ? 'Y' : 'N';
$arParams["DISPLAY_IMG_HEIGHT"] = Intval($arParams["DISPLAY_IMG_HEIGHT"]) <= 0  ? 90 : Intval($arParams["DISPLAY_IMG_HEIGHT"]);
$arParams["DISPLAY_IMG_WIDTH"] = Intval($arParams["DISPLAY_IMG_WIDTH"]) <= 0  ? 90 : Intval($arParams["DISPLAY_IMG_WIDTH"]);
```

Я поменяла в самом родном компоненте битрикса. Ничего не получилось.

**UPD от 21.12**

```html
    if($arResult["USER_VALS"]["CONFIRM_ORDER"] == "Y")
 {
  
  if(strlen($arResult["REDIRECT_URL"]) > 0)
  {
   ?>
   <script>
   
   //top.location.replace = '<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arResult["REDIRECT_URL"])?>';
                             window.top.location.href='<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arResult["REDIRECT_URL"])?>'; // Вот здесь, она за что отвечает?
   //setInterval("window.top.location.href='<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arResult["REDIRECT_URL"])?>';",2000);
   //-->
   </script>
   <?
                      
   die();
  }
  else
   include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$templateFolder."/confirm.php");
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оплата с аккаунта если отключена опция PAY_FROM_ACCOUNT не будет работать, скорее всего 2 варианта надо искать

1. вы смотрите не тот компонент
2. В каком-то из локальных модулях или в init.php созданы события на оформление покупки в которых вручную применен метод CSaleUserAccount::Withdraw или CSaleUserAccount::Pay

Comment: в init.php смотрела-его нет. Вернее был, но я его убрала 3 месяца назад.

Comment: Далее, я убрала в настройках модуля битрикса Путь к пользовательским файлам-обработчикам платежных систем:

Comment: тоже не помогло.

Comment: не получается найти пользователя.

Comment: вот то что вы сделали - "Я поменяла в самом родном...  это вы зря... Решается проблема: Открываете файл страницы которая отвечает за оформление заказа. Смотрите название шаблона, ищите данный шаблон в шаблоне сайта, проверяете, что это именно он, делаете die(); если страница ломается - он. Смотрите result_modifier и component_epilog если они есть. Смотрите js возможно на кнопку отправки обработчик другой (можно отследить через консоль браузера. Находите обращение к компоненту ставите отладкуесли ничего не помогает ищите CSaleUserAccount во всех файлах. Не сработает пишите мне - помогу.

Comment: CSaleUserAccount во всех файлах вот этого нет. и яваскрипт в этом шаблоне sale.order.ajax нет

Comment: Еще раз: js не в той папке может быть, и сложно угадывать, вы точно определили что мучаете тот самый шаблон компонента? сайт есть онлайн?

Comment: да этот шаблон. судя по названию вызова шаблона, дпже вызовала die(). result_modifier и сomponent_epilog нет. у меня же sale_order_ajax. Может проблема в кеше, так как у меня кеш не удаляется совсем в админке. Я ставила три месяца назад обработчик событии, чтобы снималось со внутреннего счета. в init.php. Потом было решено, что снятие и зачисление на счет будет производить 1с.  и я убрала. все работало правильно, а потом по какой-то причине дал сбой именно сейчас.

Comment: @bilinz,  как я понимаю , проблема в коде template.php.Приведу выше.

Comment: **window.top.location.href='<?=CUtil::JSEscape($arResult["REDIRECT_URL"])?>'; // Вот здесь, она за что отвечает?** это редирект после оформления на страницу заказа.

Comment: вот происходит редирект- потом страница начинает шевелится-обновляется -и счет обнуляется.

Comment: Я даже закомментировала данную строчку , поставила на место нее       include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$templateFolder."/confirm.php"); все равно также.